# How do I deploy my Angular project using Json Server?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, vercel, json-server

I currently have a 100% working project in Angular, still using JSON-Server for my database (data.js):

```
module.exports = function () {
  var data = {
    nutritionalPlans: [
      {
        id: 1,
        titleNutritionalPlan: "Plan Nutricional de Stan Marsh Semana 1",
        statusNutritionalPlan: "Activo",
        objectiveNutritionalPlan: "Aumentar Masa Muscular",
        descriptionNutritionalPlan:
          "La dieta para aumentar la masa muscular incluye alimentos ricos en proteínas, grasas buenas y carbohidratos complejos ricos en fibras.",
        startDateNutritionalPlan: "2022-04-20",
        endDateNutritionalPlan: "2022-04-26",
        recommendationsNutritionalPlan:
          "Para cumplir el objetivo no debe saltarse las comidas y debe consumir más calorías de lo que gasta.",
      },
    ],
    foods: [
      {
        id:1,
        nameFood: "Pollo",
        portionsFood: "500 g",
        caloriesFood:"100 Kcal",
      },
      {
        id:2,
        nameFood: "Carne",
        portionsFood: "400 g",
        caloriesFood:"200 Kcal",
      },
      {
        id:3,
        nameFood: "Huevo",
        portionsFood: "80 g",
        caloriesFood:"80 Kcal",
      },
      {
        id:4,
        nameFood: "Queso",
        portionsFood: "100 g",
        caloriesFood:"240 Kcal",
      }
    ],

  };
  return data;
};
```

This project is a university assignment and loading it locally works great with the command `npm run server` but when I deploy to firebase or vercel, everything works except the database, apparently it doesn't connect, no I'm sure.

I tried to use the following code in my project since I saw it in a forum:

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('./data.js');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running');
});
```

But I get this error in the browser console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://gym-partner.vercel.app/dashboard/exercises' from origin 'https://gp-api-sage.vercel.app/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```